# Are parameters to range() re-evaluated at each iteration of the loop?

Tags: python, performance, range

If I use functions for range parameters, do they get called every time through?

```
for i in range(min(some_list), max(other_list)):
    ...
```

Comment: No. They will be called once.

Comment: Great.  Thanks for the quick reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It becomes easy to answer your question with a little experiment.

```
In [294]: def foo(n):
     ...:     print('in foo')
     ...:     return n
     ...: 

In [295]: for i in range(foo(5)):
     ...:     print(i)
     ...:     
in foo
0
1
2
3
4
```

So, yes, the parameters to `range` are evaluated *only once*, much like the parameters to any other function call.

Comment: Ah, great illustration.

Answer (score 0):

As stack_n_queue answered in the comments:

No, calling `for i in range(min(some_list), max(other_list))` will not result in the functions passed as arguments getting called on every iteration of `range()`

Answer (score 0):

The functions `min` and `max` are called before the `range` object/list is created i.e. argument expressions are evaluated before function call.

Therefore, they are only called once.